# What are the parts of speech in "he's fifty years old"?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, compounds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adjective Pluralization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50549/adjective-pluralization)

> 1. He's a fifty-year-old man.
> 2. He's fifty years old.

I'm fine with the first of these two sentences, in which "fifty-year-old" is a compound adjective.

In the second sentence, is "fifty years old" also a compound adjective? If not, is "fifty" an adjective modified by "years old"? I can't work it out!

Comment: Thanks @coleopterist. I missed that post when searching for my question before posting, but the answer was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second sentence, *old* is a predicate adjective which modifies the subject *He*.

The term *fifty years* is a quantifying phrase used as an adverb to modify the adjective *old*. It is a compound adverb.

> How old? Fifty years old.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find. Thanks so much!